Calculating activity of a gas
I am working through GM Anderson (2005)'s Thermodynamics of Natural Systems and am stuck on the question below regarding the calculation of activity of a crystalline substance. If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it.
Setup: Consider crystalline A to be in equilibrium with water saturated with A at a pressure of 1234.0 bars and a temperature of 567.0 $^{\text{o}}C$. A is very slightly soluble (0.001 moles/kg $H_2O$) so that P$_{H_2O}=P_{Total}$. The vapour pressure of crystalline A varies with temperature according to the relation
$$\log{P}\text{ (bars)}=\frac{-19130}{T\text{ (K)}}+7.65.$$
Its molar volume is 22.7 $\text{cm}^3\text{ mol}^{-1}$ and is essentially constant in the pressure range under consideration. The fugacity coefficient for water at this $P$ and $T$ is 0.541.
Question: Calculate the activity of crystalline A, using the following standard state: pure ideal gaseous A at $T$ and one bar.
I have calculated the vapour pressure of A at this T (840.15 K) to be $10^{-15.1197}$ bar. Then, assuming that this pressure is sufficiently low for it to approximate the fugacity of A$_(s)$, I have used
$$a_{A}=\frac{f_A}{f_A^o}=\frac{10^{-15.1197}}{1}=10^{-15.1197}.$$
However, the answers at the back of the book give $a_{A_s}=10^{-14.946}$. Have I done something wrong with the calculation, or is the book's answer wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Show more details of your symbolic and numerical scenario evaluation. // Have you considered Poynting_effect ?

Here's my take on it, though it doesn't give the textbook answer. The missing piece is that the vapor pressure equation
was measured with a much lower pressure $P_{1}$ (close to 1 bar) being exerted on the solid
than the pressure $P$. The chemical potential of the solid for the vapor
pressure measurement (where the gas is nearly ideal so $\gamma \approx 1$) is
$$\mu (T,P_{1})=\mu ^{\ominus }+RT\ln (P_{\mathrm{vap}}/P^{\ominus })$$
and for the equilibrium with the gas mixture
$$ \mu (T,P)=\mu ^{\ominus }+RT\ln (a)$$
Now for a single phase, single component system (the solid)
$$dG=VdP-SdT$$
or on a mole basis,
$$\mu =V_{\mathrm{m}}dP-S_{\mathrm{m}}dT$$
and integrating (assuming as stated that $V_{\mathrm{m}}$ is a constant) gives
$$\mu (T,P)=\mu (T,P_{1})+V_{\mathrm{m}}(P-P_{1})$$
Therefore we have
$$\mu ^{\ominus }+RT\ln (a)=\mu ^{\ominus }+RT\ln (P_{\mathrm{vap}}/P^{\ominus})+V_{\mathrm{m}}(P-P_{1})$$
or
$$\ln (a)=\ln (P_{\mathrm{vap}}/P^{\ominus })+\frac{V_{\mathrm{m}}}{RT}(P-P_{1})$$
$$a=\frac{P_{\mathrm{vap}}}{P^{\ominus }}\exp \left( \frac{V_{\mathrm{m}}(P-P_{1})}{RT}\right)$$
$$a=\frac{10^{-15.1197}~\mathrm{bar}}{1~\mathrm{bar}}\exp \left( \frac{22.7\times 10^{-6}~\mathrm{m}^{3}~\mathrm{mol}^{-1}\times (1234.0-1)\times
10^{5}~\mathrm{Pa}}{8.31446~\mathrm{J}~\mathrm{K}^{-1}~\mathrm{mol}^{-1}\times 840.15~\mathrm{K}}\right) =10^{-15.5169}$$
Although $a=\gamma P_{\mathrm{A}}/P^{\ominus }$, we haven't needed the
fugacity coefficient. It is perhaps worth mentioning that even though the
partial pressure of A in the gas is low, the gas molecules of A are
surrounded by water molecules with which thay are interacting, so the
fugacity coefficient of A in the gas mixture cannot be assumed to be close
to 1. For example if there are attractive interactions then that will favor
more A in the gas phase than if there were no interactions.

Thank you for the insightful answer! I had just assumed that the equation in the question gave a theoretical vapour pressure of A for the pressure it was at (1234 bars) and didn't consider actual gas to be present in the system interacting with the liquid!

@Gecko148 Yes, at first I also assumed that the vapor pressure eqn was at $P$, but the presence of the molar volume bothered me and I eventually realized its significance.
